# How do I attach storage shelving/rack to the floor?

Tags: shelving, storage

[This](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/storage/bulk-rack/heavy-duty/high-capacity-starter-rack-60x24x84-with-3-levels-wood-deck-1300lb-cap-per-shelf?utm_source=amaz_shop&utm_medium=shp&utm_campaign=Heavy-Duty-Rack-amaz_shop&infoParam.campaignId=T9I) is perfect for holding our computer servers. MUST be these measurements (60x24x84)

[image]

We need it to bolt/attach to the floor so it won't tip over no matter what.

1. What is a way to do that with this rack?
2. Is there a rack in these dimensions that has an easier way to attach itself to the floor? I know [Gorilla racks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017SMWT6) have built in things for this purpose but I can't find one in that size.

Comment: Alternatively, you can run wood screws through the verticals, into a stud and screw it to a wall.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have a workbench from the same company and it came with feet that allow you to easily secure it to the floor with a couple screws/lags/etc.

[image: Feet]

I would inquire with their sales to see if these are available for the shelving unit you are looking at, or if not, a similar unit.

Comment: What is this "thingy" called? Is it some kind of universal bolt down?

Comment: They call them "Leveling foot plates"